# how could i increase the accuracy of training set

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

i'm working on a classification problem (human activity classification) and i used CNN the code of model is :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(100, (2, 2), activation = 'relu', input_shape = X_train[0].shape))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
#adding pooling layer
model.add(MaxPool2D(2,2))
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

compiling  and fiting :

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = 0.001), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, validation_data= (X_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

the accuracy was like this
[image: accuracy curve]
[image: result of model fit]

how coul'd i increase the last value of accuracy ? and why the curve is increasing kinda fast?

Comment: It's clearly levelling off, but still seems to be improving at 20 epochs. It also doesn't necessarily seem to be overfitting. What does it look like after 50 epochs? One way to improve performance might be to just do more training

Comment: i did more training and it is in 90 epochs like ::::::: loss: 0.4376 - accuracy: 0.8311 - val_loss: 0.8360 - val_accuracy: 0.7500 but is there a problem with the difference between val accuracy and train accuracy from the 20 th epoch ? @A.Bollans

Comment: The divergence at epoch 20 *could* be a problem but it's hard to tell without seeing how the plots continue with more training, the blip at epoch 20 could just be noise.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few avenues you can pursue here, specifically finding answers to the following questions for your particular problem.  [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xErJGDwWqys) a great video, although not for tensorflow, but I think the question you are asking is general enough for it to apply

1. What is the right amount of time to train for? Likely the answer here is somewhere between 20 epochs and 90, more specifically, it's where your two series in the plot start to diverge; in other words, your model starts to memorize the training data at the point of divergence.  Tensorflow has early stopping [mechanisms](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) to help with this.
2. What is the performance of a naïve guesser?  Is the complexity of your model proportional to the complexity/dimensionality of the problem?
3. What is the human insight that you can bring to the problem?  Are there things you can do to the features that will help the model create separability in higher dimensions?  For example, let's say your model is going to predict what activity a person is going to do at a given point in time.  In this case, information related to people might be separate from time and activity data.  You can create features that represent combinations of other features (assuming you have a lot of data), and encode this and feed it to your model.  You can create embeddings in your model to get your model to deal with the sparsity that occurs when you combine such categorical features.

Another aspect of this that I think is very important to answer is "Why am I solving this problem?".  In some cases, the answer might be "I want to learn X", in which case you might approach it differently.  For example, if it's all tabular data, you might have more interpretable/better results using something like scikit-learn using a tree based model. It also, of course, depends on the amount and type of data you have. [Nested cross-validation](https://inria.github.io/scikit-learn-mooc/python_scripts/cross_validation_nested.html) can give you great insight into what are the combinations of hyperparameters and features that will produce a model that generalizes, and also about the variation you can expect to see on unseen data.

Best of luck!